# dynamic path to resource in springmvc

Tags: java, spring

In Java-Jersey, it is possible to receive a dynamic path to a resource, e.g.

localhost:8080/webservice/this/is/my/dynamic/path

```
@GET
@Path("{dynamicpath : .+}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)     
public String get(@PathParam("dynamicpath") String p_dynamicpath) {
     return p_dynamicpath;
}
```

prints out: this/is/my/dynamic/path

**Question: how to do this in Spring MVC?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple items inside your path you can access the dynamic path values like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String dynPath = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    System.out.println("Dynamic Path: " + dynPath );
    return dynPath;
}
```

If you know beforehand hoe many levels of path variables you'll have you can code them explicit like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{path1}/{path2}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(@PathVariable("path1") String path1,
          @PathVariable("path2") String path2,
          HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String dynPath = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    System.out.println("Dynamic Path: " + dynPath );
    return dynPath;
}
```

If you want to see the String returned in your browser, you need to declare the method `@ResponseBody` as well (so the String you return is the content of your response):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String get(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
```

Comment: thanks! now, for some reason, my webapp changes to 
WEB-INF/jsp/my/entered/path.jsp ... :-) must be some config error i guess ...

Comment: No. that's just Spring MVC rendering the **view** you returned (the path string)

Comment: See my edit for how to get String as response in Browser